# Kubuntu 15.10, doubling on-screen display of sound bar after updating from kde4

Tags: kubuntu, plasma, kde5, kmix

[http://imgur.com/avuHhfS](https://imgur.com/avuHhfS)
The bottom sound bar does not disappear nor changes look when I change plasma theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you are using both kmix and plasma-pa app, you can disable one of them during boot or just uninstall one of them.

If you want the bottom bar to disappear then you can uninstall kmix :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge kmix
```

Comment: I actually already got it figured out (used xwininfo on both windows to get their correspnding processes) and uninstalled kmix.

That successfully solved the issue.